# Silverlight 4: Image Resizer

Tags: image, silverlight-4.0, resize

I want to know how to resize an image in Silverlight **without using any 3rd party DLL** such as FJCore and the like

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Heres a very good Video Cast about Silverlight Optimization and Profiling (you can find what you want in 28 minute of video)

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/MED07

And here you can find source code from this talk

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slperf/archive/2011/04/15/silverlight-performance-mix-11.aspx

Comment: It has nothing about author's question.

Comment: You didn't watched video cast properly. So go, watch it first and then u wont going to post veird comments anymore. Remember, no one gonna do a homework for u.